# Nginx and Dart Server

Tags: nginx, dart

I learned Dart as my first web development language and produced my first web server, learned some Docker for deployment, but I keep seeing terms like apache, nginx, load balancing, etc.

Nginx big plus is that asynchronous but Dart is all ready asynchronous, I already serve static files with `shelf`, so what would be good reasons to learn and use nginx?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know nginx myself but such servers are usually optimized for serving static resources like images or CSS or any other files with good caching. I t might be a good idea to not expose your application directly to the web for security reasons and shield it by a well tested server. Such servers also might provide some features like, caching, load balancing or virtual domains, and probably many more.